# Finding order of pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have some problems with the following excersice: Find the order of the pole of: 
$$\frac{1}{(2\cos z -2 + z^2)^2}$$ at $z=0$. I thought it is maybe better to work here with $1/f$ and find the order of the zero at $z=0$. But I don't know how to continue. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the Taylor expansion of $\cos$. Use as many terms as you need to determine the order.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!

Comment: The pole is of order $8$.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I don't understand how this helps me to get the order, because then I get: (2(1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-..+..) - 2 + z^2)^2 and I do not see how I

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal, that is indeed the correct answer, but how do you see that so easy?

Comment: @Leslie: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632623/singularity-of-fz-frac-sin-ze-zz-1/632647#632647).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\cos z-2+z^2=2\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}-\ldots\right)-2+z^2=$$

$$=\frac{z^4}{12}-\frac{2z^6}{6!}+\ldots=z^4\left(\frac1{12}-\frac{2z^2}{6!}+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\left(2\cos x-2+z^2\right)^2=z^8\left(\frac1{144}+\frac{z^2}{3\cdot 6!}+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\frac1{(2\cos z-2+z^2)^2}=\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Oo thank you now I see it. It is really easy actually. I just had to write it out and forgot about the outer square in the beginning!

Comment: Indeed so, @Leslie