# Singularity of $f(z)=\frac {\sin z}{e^{-z}+z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What's the kind of singularity $z_0=0$ of $f(z)$: $$f(z)=\frac {\sin z}{e^{-z}+z-1}$$

I know I should write it in the form:

$$f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$$

but I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you advance. Recalling the Taylor series, we have 
$$ \frac {\sin z}{e^{-z}+z-1} = \frac{ \sin z}{(1-z+z^2/2-\dots)+z-1}=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2/2-z^3/3!+\dots} $$

$$ = \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2( 1/2-z/3!+\dots)} . $$

Now, you can see that the [order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points) of the pole is $1$.

Comment: why is the pole 1 and not 2? The power of z, in the denominator, is 2 and not 1.

Comment: @JamesWatson: Because $ \lim_{z\to 0} z f(z) =2  $. Note that, $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\,z\,f(z)=\frac{z\sin z}{e^{-z}+z-1}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z+z\cos z}{-e^{-z}+1}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2\cos z-z\sin z}{e^{-z}}=2$$

and thus this is a pole of order one and residue $\;2\;$ .

**Caution:** The above approach is works nicely mostly when we have a pole of low order ($\;1,2,3\;$) , otherwise it can be weary to repeat the above with $\;z^2f(z)\;,\;\;z^3f(z)\;$ and etc. But it is usually so simple that is, imo., worth a shot.