# Calculation of Complex Residue $\frac{e^z-1}{z^2\sin(z)}$ in$ z_0 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a comparing. I'd know the residue of

$$\frac{e^z−1}{z^2\sin(z)}; z_0=0$$

I have wrote down the series expansion of $e^z$ and $\sin(z)$ and then I've made in evidence $z^3...$  in the end I executed the limit operation for $z\to0$.

The result is $1/6$
Is It correct?

I would avoid the third derivation of function.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632623/singularity-of-fz-frac-sin-ze-zz-1/632647#632647).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let$$(\ast)=\frac{\mathrm e^z-1}{z^2\sin z},$$ then $$(\ast)=\frac{z+z^2/2+z^3/6+O(z^4)}{z^3-z^5/6+O(z^7)}=\frac{1+z/2+z^2/6+O(z^3)}{z^2(1-z^2/6+O(z^4))},$$ hence
$$(\ast)=\frac{1+z/2+z^2/3+O(z^3)}{z^2}=\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{2z}+\frac13+O(z).$$

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand. What have you done in this step: $$\frac{1+z/2+z^2/6+O(z^3)}{z^2(1-z^2/6+O(z^4))}=\frac{1+z/2+z^2/3+O(z^3)}{z^2}$$

Comment: $1/(1-z^2/6)=1+z^2/6+O(z^4)$ then multiply by the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{e^z-1}{z^2\sin z}=\frac{z+z^2/2+\cdots}{z^2(z-z^3/6+\cdots)}=\frac{z+z^2/2+\cdots}{z^3}\times(1+z^2/6+\cdots)\\=\frac 1{z^2}+\frac {\frac  12} z+\cdots$$
hence the residue is $\frac 1 2$.