# Classifying the singularity of $( e^{\sqrt{z}} - e^{-\sqrt z})/\sin \sqrt{z}$ at zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function,
$$ \frac{ e^{\sqrt{z}} - e^{-\sqrt z}}{\sin \sqrt z} $$

Does this function have removable singularities? to me it seems like there is a branch point at $z=0$. Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632623/singularity-of-fz-frac-sin-ze-zz-1/632647#632647). Here is a start.
$$ \frac{ e^{\sqrt{z}} - e^{-\sqrt z}}{\sin \sqrt z}= \frac{(1+\sqrt{z}-\dots)-(1-\sqrt{z}+\dots)}{\sqrt{z}-\frac{\sqrt{z}}{3!}+\dots}. $$

Can you see what's going on?

Comment: So with that, I can divide numerator and denominator by $ \sqrt z $ that tells me the fact that this is a removable singularity !! ** So it doesn't have branch cuts ? **

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the function $g(w) = (e^w-e^{-w})/\sin w$, which has a removable singularity at $w=0$. The question to address: is $g$ an *even* function? If it is, then yes, we can plug $\sqrt{z}$ into it and not worry about branches at all: the composition will be holomorphic near zero. (All powers in the Taylor series of an even function at $0$ are even.)

So: is $g$ even? I guess it is!